# CSS Masonry layout Overlapping with Dynamic content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, masonry

I am using Desandro's Masonry with angular-js , it works fine but that is only if all the content in it is remains static. Inside each grid item i have another div which shows on mouse-over and hides on mouseleave.

But whenever i mouseover the inner div display, overlapping the bellow grid item. since the height of the parent div increases.

```
JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/w31s1hd6/2/
```

is there any way to adjust the column bellow automatically maintaining the same margin between grid items, whenever this change occurs? or some better design?

Thanks